# How to properly XML-serialize collections with an extensible object hierarchy in .NET?

Tags: .net, oop, xml-serialization

Scenario:

1. I got 4 classes, `Configuration`, `Option`, `Option1` and `Option2`
2. `Option1` and `Option2` inherit from `Option`
3. `Configuration` has a property that is of type `List<Option>`, in which I intend to store objects that descend from `Option`
4. `Option` is abstract, and will never be used to construct an actual instance.

The problem:

- When I simply annotate these objects and members with simple `[XmlType(...)]` and `[XmlElement(...)]` attributes, the serialization of the objects in the collection ends up different than what I want
- If I add the necessary `[XmlArray(...)]` and `[XmlArrayItem(...)]` attributes, it looks like I want, but then I have to specify at compile-time a known list of item types, making extensibility impossible

Here's an example [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) script that you can run:

```
void Main()
{

    var Configuration = new Configuration();
    Configuration.Options.Add(new Option1());
    Configuration.Options.Add(new Option2());

    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Configuration), new Type[]
    {
        typeof(Option1),
        typeof(Option2),
    });
    var ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
    ns.Add(string.Empty, string.Empty);

    using (var writer = new StringWriter())
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, Configuration, ns);
        writer.ToString().Dump();
    }
}

[XmlType("configuration")]
public class Configuration
{
    private readonly List<Option> _Options = new List<Option>();

    [XmlElement("options")]
    public List<Option> Options { get { return _Options; } }

    [XmlArray("options2")]
    [XmlArrayItem(typeof(Option1))]
    [XmlArrayItem(typeof(Option2))]
    public List<Option> Options2 { get { return _Options; } }
}

public class Option { }

[XmlType("option1")]
public class Option1 : Option { }

[XmlType("option2")]
public class Option2 : Option { }
```

When you run this, you get the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<configuration>
  <options d2p1:type="option1" xmlns:d2p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" />
  <options d2p1:type="option2" xmlns:d2p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" />
  <options2>
    <option1 />
    <option2 />
  </options2>
</configuration>
```

Notice how the first property, `options` is serialized quite different from `options2`, but they have the same content.

Basically, I'd like to have the serialized xml look like `options2`, but without having to specify the allowed type of classes through attributes, since this will make extensibility impossible.

If I have to provide them through something that can be altered at runtime, that's fine, but hardcoded at compile-time is a no-go.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are going to have to look at [`XmlAttributeOverrides`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributeoverrides.aspx), which lets you supply the attributes at runtime. This is not *trivial*, but not mind-melting either. The biggest catch: when you use the constructor that accepts `XmlAttributeOverrides` an assembly is generated **every time**, so be sure to cache and re-use the `XmlSerializer` instance - otherwise you will leak assemblies (they can't be collected).

To implement you would have an `XmlAttributes` instance to which you tweak `XmlArray` and `XmlArrayItems`, then use `XmlAttributeOverrides.Add(Type,Member,XmlAttributes)` to associate that with `"Options2"`.

Comment: Is that the only option? I'm hoping to use the code for both a .net project and a monotouch project, so assembly/code generation isn't a good solution.

Comment: @Lasse that's how XmlSerializer works in .net (unless you use "sgen") - could well be that the Mono impl is different, though